# How to turn off depth filter for Azure Kinect, for borders and flying pixels?

Tags: azurekinect

Is there any way I can turn off the flying pixels filter of the Azure Kinect? I call "flying pixels" those pixels on the border of an object, that are flying between the foreground and the background object. I observed that when the 2 are far enough, they are filtered automatically. On the contrary, when the 2 objects have similar depth, the flying pixels aren't filtered out, but a mean filter seems to be applied anyways.
Any idea if I can control that in any way? I checked the Azure Kinect Viewer as well as the SDK and couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depth engine does certain filtering to help improving the overall depth quality, which is built into the sensor. Currently there is no way to modify those settings or turn off the filter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's too bad, but at least now I know there is nothing I can do about it.